# what to do for this.............every time i run my android project i got this

Tags: android, flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Wrnglr.gradle\caches\jars-8\f1dd8e6ec0db9b111f425c513285a977\auto-value-annotations-1.6.2.jar.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: reinstall your android sdk

Answer (score 0):

try the following :
1- remove .gradle file
2- stop firewall
3- run vpn like proton
4- run again